# I added a bump to a material, but the color doesn't seem right

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I made a texture with nodes on Blender Cycles, i added a image texture then a bump, and the bump works but the image looks too ''white''. 
I need the color back to normal but with the bump, is this possible or i'll have to also make a new material?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is being caused by the fact that you have three shaders, but only one is influenced by the image texture.

Plug your colour map (top image texture) into the colour input of the other diffuse shader and the glossy shader.

Comment: Can you please give me the answer with images so i'll follow the steps then give you the correct answer?

Comment: You shouldn't need any images, this is straightforward enough

Comment: @beavoru This is quite basic. Please read the answer carefully and at least try to get the result before asking for clarification and/or images. Thanks.

Comment: Already worked :)

Comment: Great, glad to have been of help :-)